# On related list for an object, the "view all" button is not working. Throwing invalid page when clicking on "view all"

Tags: community

We have a community page, and when we go to the Account object, and click on a particular Account, and then navigate to the related tab, we can see all the related objects.  For each object, small number of records are shown.  If we want to see all records related to that particular account, we usually click, "View All" at the bottom of each related object.  When we click "View All" it shows us "Invalid Page" and does not show all of the related accounts. Salesforce support has not been able to help us resolve the issue.  Any idea?  Please see screenshot for information. The community page is only for internal users and all profiles have "view all" functionality on all object level. [image]

[image]

Comment: What is the URL in the address bar on the invalid page? Specifically everything after the \ at the end of your company url.

Comment: Hi gNerb, 
The URL address bar on the invalid page is, "https://domain.force.com/pam/s/account/001t000000*****/***-afb?tabset-81d89001=2 ...it should show the related list API name that it is related to, however, it navigates to the above url.  The *** is simply hidden for privacy issue from the chat.   However, it does have the full account ID and the account name but does not have the related API name instead shows, "tabset".

Comment: Hi gNerb, any idea regarding the issue? Salesforce support has not been able to provide a solution either yet.

Comment: refreshing the page. If that doesn't do the trick, give your Salesforce admin the following error ID, and describe what youtrying to accomplish. Error ID: 1794849773 This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: siteforce:designTimeMode$controller$handlePageLoadingError [Cannot read property 'match' of undefined] Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.comm.runtime.components.aura.components.siteforce.controller.PubliclyCacheableComponentLoaderController/ACTION$getPageComponent Failing descriptor: {siteforce:designTimeMode$controller$handlePageLoadingError}

Comment: Hey, sorry I am pretty busy these days and haven't had the time to put this to the test. When adding additional information its best to [add it to the question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/296512/edit) and not to the comments. Error messages should be added as quotes to your question.

Comment: The issue was from salesforce side and it seems like 13 other org's were also affected.  Nothing from our side.  Salesforce was able to resolve it on the 5th day.  Took slightly longer than expected.  Thank you gNerb for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was from salesforce side and it seems like other org's were also affected.  No fix was done from our side as the issue resided on the script from the backend.